# Cannot login to site after domain .COM address pointed at .ORG

Tags: domain

We recently acquired the .ORG version of our domain. For migration, the IT staff pointed the .COM domain over to the .ORG address (e.g., http://domain.com/page -->  --> http://domain.org/page). The WordPress site seems to be displaying HTML content fine, but no one can login. I cannot access the Dashboard as an admin. Password reset emails are not being sent, and attempts to reset the password via other means (http://codex.wordpress.org/Resetting_Your_Password) still does not allow login. Troubleshooting advice welcome.

Comment: If you're changing the domain, have a look [**here**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL). Pointing the old domain to the new domain isn't enough and will cause login problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the site address in your `wp-config.php` file:

```
define('WP_HOME','http://domain.org');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://domain.org');
```

There are other ways to do this too. See http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL